# Como fazer os dados retornarem em php array

Tags: php, pdo

Preciso retornar os dados em um array.
Estou fazendo isso, mas os dados não retornam:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("conexao.php");
$pdo = conectar();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

/*$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$idCategoria = $request->idCategoria;*/

$id_categoria = $_GET['idCategoria'];
echo $id_categoria;

$buscarSubcategoria=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sub_cat_entrada WHERE id_categoria = :id_categoria");
$buscarSubcategoria->bindValue(':id_categoria', $id_categoria, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$buscarSubcategoria->execute();

//$buscarSubcategoria->debugDumpParams();


$return = array();

while ($linha=$buscarSubcategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return[] = array(
    'id_subcategoria'   => $linha['id_subcategoria'],
    'subcategoria'  => utf8_encode($linha['subcategoria']),
);
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Sua consulta retornar uma linha ou mais?

Comment: Mais de uma linha.

Comment: Assim funciona? `while ($linha=$buscarSubcategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return[] = $linha;   
}`

Comment: Não, só apareceu o 1 do echo $id_categoria;

Comment: Se você der um `print_r($return)` ve o array corretamente? isso aí vai para um javascript?

Comment: Vai pro angular, esse resultado.
Dei o print_r($return) e apareceram os dados e formato de "árvore" de array.
Estou rodando o código no POSTMAN do chrome, pra testar.

Comment: Será que o problema não é do lado do javascript?

Comment: Coloquei o meu código angular de retorno, na descrição do post @rray

Comment: Descobri o problema.
Os dados não aparecem porque tem palavras com acento.
Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Consegui... Os dois drop-down funcionando.
Correção na descrição.